# localize date time in python

Tags: python, datetime, flask

**Overview** *I receive the timestamp from server_x, my application is on server_y, both are in different regions, my application calls server_x api and receives json which has timestamp, now i need to perform some calculation on server_y, for that i need to make sure that the timestamp i receive from server_x could be used to covert the local datetime of server_y , so both are in sync*

I want to convert `datetime.now()` to the timezone I receive from server for e.g., UTC-07:00

Current solution, I pass `server_timestamp` to the function and then I pass its zone info to the `datetime.now`

```py
    Server_timestamp = "2020-04-04T10:24:49.000-0700"
    dt = datetime.strptime(Server_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    convert_local = datetime.now(dt.tzinfo)
```

**Problem**: 
I need to save the timezone of the server in `db` and then use that instead of passing `server_timestamp` everytime, the `tzinfo` gives a type `datetime.timezone = UTC-07:00`, after storing this string how can I use it to change the localtime.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean to get the timezone of the user on the server or do you pass in a timezone in a input?

Comment: I receive the timestamp from server_x, my application is on server_y, both are in different regions, my application calls server_x api and receives json which has timestamp, now i need to perform some calculation on server_y, for that i need to make sure that the timestamp i receive from server_x could be used to covert the local datetime of server_y , so both are in sync

Comment: why not keep it simple and run all your servers in UTC?

Comment: the api server is not owned by me, i have to come up with the solution on my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a solution.
I now save the last 5 char of the timestamp in the db "-0700".

```
time_zone = query_from_db
tz = datetime.strptime(time_zone, "%z")
datetime_now = datetime.now(tz.tzinfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that utilizes the `datetime` library to convert a `datetime` object from one timezone to another:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def convert_tz(dt, current_tz, out_tz):
    return dt.replace(tzinfo=current_tz).astimezone(tz=out_tz)

now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
convert = datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo

print(now)
print(utc_to_local(now, now.tzinfo, convert))
```

Output:

```
2020-05-10 17:02:44.245703-04:00
2020-05-10 16:02:44.245703-05:00
```

I used the `pytz` library for demonstration purposes. For you, to get the server's timezone, use the line `datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo`.

Comment: `pytz` doesn't seem particularly useful here since the OP has a UTC offset, not a specific timezone. Also, `datetime.now().astimezone(dt.tzinfo)` is basically the same as the OP alread has in his example, `datetime.now(dt.tzinfo)`. Oh and by the way, if you *have* a `pytz.timezone`, use `localize` (and `normalize` if needed), not `replace` + `astimezone`

Comment: @MrFuppes These are good points. I'll change my answer if the OP wants a fleshed out version of this, but I agree with your suggestion above about keeping all the times UTC.